# ls no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to rewrite some command like this `command ls /home/user/tst_dir/ | wc -l` to test usage of another function. So I wrote this

```
command() {
local com=""${1}" "${2}" "${3}" "${4}" "${5}""
echo $com
`"${com}"`
}

command ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ \| wc -l
```

but I got

> ls: no such file or directory error.

Also directory definitely exists and I have all rights on it. I even tried to copy `ls` command from error message and execute it and it did. So what can be wrong?

Here I run under `/bin/bash/ -vx`

```
+ gsutil ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ '|' wc -l
+ echo ls
ls
+ echo /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/
/home/aliashenko/tst_dir/
+ echo '|'
|
+ echo wc
wc
+ echo -l
-l
+ 'ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ | wc -l'
/home/aliashenko/2.sh: line 31: ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ | wc -l: No such file or directory
+ local 'com=ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ | wc -l'
+ echo ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ '|' wc -l
ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ | wc -l
"${com}"
++ 'ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ | wc -l'
/home/aliashenko/2.sh: line 34: ls /home/aliashenko/tst_dir/ | wc -l: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why the backquotes?

Comment: What is `command` function supposed to be doing? btw `command` is already a command.

Comment: Don't put commands in vars.

Comment: @anubhava It is actually gsutil but it does not matter

Comment: Use `#!/bin/bash -vx` as first line of your shell script

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch edited

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)